# ¿Dónde está console en la carpeta /app en un nuevo php proyecto creado con Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony2

Quería utilizar por primera vez el terminal para ejecutar un comando php con el framework Symfony. Sin embargo, he hecho un simple proyecto de creación con`$ symfony new myproject`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desde la versión 3.0 de Symfony, la utilidad de consola ha sido movida a `bin/console`, dentro del directorio del proyecto creado.

Answer (score 1):

Es correcto como dice Murano, sin embargo, para desarrollar con la versión LTS puedes usar

```
symfony new Proyecto lts
```

Así te aseguras que tu código va a estar sobre la rama estable y de mantenimiento largo.

Para versiones menores 2.8, lo encuentras en app/console, para superiores a 2.8 en bin/console

Comment: Muchas gracias ! ¿ Pero que es la versión LTS ?

Comment: @Marine1 LTS son las siglas de "Long Time Support", o soporte a largo plazo.